# how do i do the derivative of frobenius norm

Tags: matrix-decomposition

I am trying to do matrix factorization.

$ \frac{1}{2} \vert\vert X - WZ ^T \vert\vert ^2_F $

How do I find the derivative wrt W ?

I am just told that it is $  W^T = (Z^TZ + \lambda I_K)^{-1}Z^TX^T $

I come from a lousy school please help show me the way.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=matrix+derivative+answers%3A1.  Generally, learning good searching techniques can compensate for deficiencies in one's background or resources.  Another essential skill to cultivate is how to formulate a question: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for a few pointers.